# Instance has no attribute - Deque Library

Tags: python, class, collections, attributes, queue

I am trying to use a method from the deque library (from collections). But I get the error "MyQueue instance has no attribute 'append'". But I'm sure that deque has an "append" method. What is causing this error?

```
import copy
from collections import deque

class MyQueue:
    def __init__(self):
        self = deque()
    def push(self, val):
        self.append(val)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this by wrapping a `deque` instance with your `MyQueue`:

```
from collections import deque


class MyQueue(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._queue = deque(*args, **kwargs)

    def push(self, value):
        self._queue.append(value)

    def pop(self):
        return self._queue.pop()
```

This would be a good approach if you want to use the `deque` internally but are interested in providing a simplified interface compared to what `deque` already provides.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by subclassing `deque`:

```
from collections import deque


class MyQueue(deque):
    def push(self, val):
        self.append(val)
```

which could then be used like this:

```
>>> q = MyQueue()
>>> q.push(5)
>>> q
deque([5])
```

For more information about classes and inheritance in Python, see the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html).

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do it without changing the specification of MyQueue?

Comment: @Essam I'm not sure I entirely understand what you mean. Can you be a bit more specific about what you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to keep "class MyQueue()" as it is. Is there anything I can change within the definitions of init or push to make it work, or is subclassing MyQueue the only way to do it?

Comment: @Essam You could wrap a `deque` instance and then provide whatever method interface you wanted. I'll add that as a separate answer.